How can I achieve the desired output shown in the provided image?
Here, my code:
            #distance of pose
            if results.pose_landmarks:
                for pose in poses:
                    landmark_attribute = getattr(mp_pose.PoseLandmark, pose)
                    landmark_values = []
                    for suffix in dot_suffixes:
                        landmark_final = getattr(results.pose_landmarks.landmark[landmark_attribute], suffix)
                        if suffix == 'x' or suffix == 'z':
                            landmark_final *= 640
                        elif suffix == 'y':
                            landmark_final *= 320
                        landmark_values += (landmark_final,)
                    distance_data[pose].append(landmark_values)

with open('distance_pose.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
                writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
                writer.writerow([item for sublist in [distance_data[pose] for pose in poses] for item in sublist])

I'm working on a project where I need to achieve a specific output layout as depicted in this image in link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qX5Hs7PaQaUf8O7Y_2y2HX9pQiU2uV2q/view?usp=sharing
I've tried, but I'm not getting the desired result. Could someone please guide me on how to achieve exactly like in the picture?

Can you give example input data and the corresponding output you hope to achieve.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kOjjoVH2vbzZCCDvmNodO3ZquC1T2FBD/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d8L4LIVK_tpeBlQ7X411Dw20idLPqFSH/view?usp=sharing -> corresponding output that I hope to achieve

You can do this with Pandas.
In your corresponding output you have the data splitting the row on to a new row at column 'F' and in your drawn image it extends to L and 'so on'. I dont know if you mean to spit the rows as well.
This code sample keeps the rows intact. There are 33 columns for each row in the input CSV file and that is expanded to 99 columns in the output CSV.
I have included a Header row for the CSV consisting of the Column Letters as used by Excel so the Headers are from 'A' - 'CU'. If you dont want Headers you can set header=False like the 'to_excel' example. You can also remove the line that renames the headers.
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl  # Use Openpyxl util to get letter for column number 


### Creates a list of letters per Excel column naming to size specified.
def headers(size):
    return [openpyxl.utils.cell.get_column_letter(x) for x in range(1, size+1)]


input_csv_file = 'distance_pose.csv'
output_csv_file = 'desired_output.csv'

### Create dataframe from the input CSV file
df = pd.read_csv(input_csv_file, header=None)

### Remove the open or close bracket from every cell where they exist
df.replace(r'\(|\)', '', regex=True, inplace=True)

### Create a new dataframe df2 from expanding each cell to 3 numbers
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df.columns = [i for i in range(df.shape[1])]
for x in range(len(df.columns)):
    df2 = pd.concat([df2, df[x].str.split(',', expand=True)], axis=1)

### Change the Headers to letters (Excel Column Letters)
df2 = df2.set_axis(headers(df2.shape[1]), axis=1)

### Write to Excel sheet if that is desired
# df2.to_excel('distance_pose.xlsx', header=False, index=False)

### Write to CSV file
df2.to_csv(output_csv_file, index=False)

